# Python Asyncio TimeoutError (tasks.loop)

Tags: python, timeout, infinite-loop

I have a script that should run endless. My problem is that after about 10 minutes a timeout error appears.
I tried a try/except, if it is catched, the start method should be called again. But this does not work. The catch work, but the start method cannot be called again.

Here is my code:

```
    @tasks.loop()
    async def beginn(self):
        print(something)
        self.csvToList()
        await self.find_price()

    def start():
        try:
            print("run")
            mon = monitor()
            mon.beginn.start()
            client.run(token)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout")
            start()

    start()
```

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJycf.png)

[And for the line numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2QCo.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code, you wrote `client.run(token)`. So maybe this is discord.py.
I think the best solution to this, in order not to end this loop is this:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def beginn(self):
    print(something)
    self.csvToList()
    await self.find_price()

@beginn.before_loop
async def before():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")



beginn.start()
bot.run(token)
```

Do not forget to delete **YOUR start()** function in order this work properly.